# PHP file_get_contents() working incorrectly after hosting change

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-404, file-get-contents

My website uses `file_get_contents()` on various pages, to retrieve source from other pages on my server. This worked fine until I changed my hosting provider today. The function will not return anything, unless I point it to the homepage (where it then retrieves the homepages source).

The function is enabled when checking the php.ini file, but i have a feeling this has something to do with how my website works.

I've created a single `404 error page` (the homepage) which catches all requested urls, checks the mysql database for the source, and retrieves it if it exists. The whole site runs through the `404 error page`. All of the existing 'pages' return the source as expected, but if, within that source, i use file_get_contents() to retrieve source from another page, the function will return nothing, and that part of the source will stay blank.

The main trouble is, I've made a 'virtual' stylesheet using my funny `404 website` engine, that most of the pages retrieve their stylesheet from, and as file_get_contents() only works when pointing towards the homepage, no stylesheet is loaded in the  tags, and the page is left .. looking terrible.

Any suggestions? I know the system works fine theoretically, as I used it on my previous host.

Comment: What does `var_dump(function_exists('file_get_contents'));` output?

Comment: your using the server side path in file_get_contents() ?

Comment: If `file_get_contents()` retrieves your homepage then it's working (which it should, since it's part of the PHP core). The server logs might give you a clue, or try echoing the exact location that `file_get_contents()` is trying to read - chances are it's looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Amal Murali, 'bool(true)'

Comment: thats unlikley to be the full server path

Comment: @Mike W, yes, retrieving the homepages source with the function works fine, just no pages after the .com/ forward slash.

Comment: @Dagon , sorry, it was:

`echo(file_get_contents("http://www.shadespeed.com/stylesheet"));`

etc.

Comment: Why are you getting the file via http, though the web server, when you can get the file from the local file system? Which is faster and uses less resources.

Comment: Aye, a URL requires that the fopen wrappers are enabled to do what you are trying to do. I'd suggest using a local file path as well.

Comment: @Dagon The whole website consists of only 3 or 4 php files. All other files are virtual, and held in an sql database (retrieved with the 404 error page when the page isnt found) - the whole site revolves around the use of the 404 error page, requested url and the mysql database (which holds the source)

Comment: then you should be retrieving them directly from the database.

Comment: as rob says, acces it from db, and i really hope when you say "revolves around the use of the 404 error page" your not really returning the 404  headers to the clinet

Comment: Ok, yes, I understand that that'd make more sense, but my system gives me more flexibility (in case I'd like to replace a fake path with a real file). It worked fine with the old host, I'd just like to know what's different with this one, and why file_get_contents() doesn't retrieve data from 404 error pages any more.

Comment: good luck with that, i have a pathological problem with helping people do things the wrong way.

Comment: I believe you're right, I will simply re-design the editor system to create new files, instead of working through the 404 Error page. Thank you.